# Removing tefillin, Uva Letziyon, and יהי רצון שנשמור חקיך

Tags: tefilla, blessing, tefilin, kedusha-prayer

There used to be, according to Minhag Eretz Yisrael, a bracha that was said on removing tefillin: אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו לשמור חקיו.  [The Shulchan Aruch rules not to say it](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.29.1), and as far as I know, nobody does anymore.

The Shulchan Aruch [also says](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56500/11532) that you shouldn't take off your tefillin before the kedusha of Uva Letziyon.  I can't help but notice that the last paragraph of Uva Letziyon starts with יהי רצון מלפניך...שנשמור חקיך בעולם הזה.  Is there a connection to the no-longer-practiced bracha?

Comment: I've heard that suggested before, and I believe Hildesheimer suggests it in an article in Sinai.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.29.3?lang=bi

Comment: I think I've seen in avudraham, taht that yehi rotzon is for post tefilin.

Answer (score 1):

Well spotted! The Mishna Brura (29-1) explains that they used to say a bracha because they wore the tfillin the whole day and held that night-time isn't a time for tfillin, hence taking off the tfillin before nightfall, was a mitzva which required a bracha. We hold that night-time is zman tfillin (and the only reason we don't wear them then is out of fear that we might fall asleep), hence we don't make a bracha when removing them.
The Dirshu edition of the Mishna Brura points to the MB in 25-59, who brings from the Elya Rabbah that on Rosh Chodesh one should remove the tfillin just before saying  יה"ר מלפניך...שנשמור חקיך בעולם הזה. The Elya Rabbah himself (https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41130&st=&pgnum=19) writes that the reason for that is because of the ברכה that they used to say.