Why not recite a beracha when taking off tefillin
According to a sugyah in the Talmud Yerushalmi there were rabbis who held the opinion you should recite a beracha when taking off tefillin:

כשהוא חולצן מהו אומר ברוך אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו לשמור חוקיו. ואתיא
כמאן דמר בחוקת תפילין הכתוב מדבר ברם כמאן דמר בחוקת הפסח הכתוב מדבר לא
בדא.
When he takes them off, what does he say? “Praised Who sanctified us
by His commandments and commanded us to obey His laws.” That follows
the opinion that the verse speaks about the law of tefillin. However,
according to those who say that the verse speaks about the law of
Passover, that does not apply.

Why nowadays do almost no Jews practice that, with the only exception I know being rabbi David Bar Hayim?

Since the Shulchan Aruch 29:1 writes that we do not make such a bracha.
The Mishna Berura (1) explains that in Eretz Yisrael(Yerushalmi) they held that one must remove their teffilin before nightfall as an obligation.  However ,us(bavli) holds that one can technically wear teffilin into the night according to the strict letter of the law,rather we do not wear teffilin at night because we are afraid one may fall asleep and pass gas in them.

Even "we" agree about Friday though

See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135889/removing-tefillin-uva-letziyon-and-%d7%99%d7%94%d7%99-%d7%a8%d7%a6%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%a9%d7%a0%d7%a9%d7%9e%d7%95%d7%a8-%d7%97%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%9a?rq=1
"There used to be, according to Minhag Eretz Yisrael, a bracha that was said on removing tefillin: אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו לשמור חקיו. The Shulchan Aruch rules not to say it, and as far as I know, nobody does anymore."

And there is a detailed discussion under the heading "Does One Recite a Blessing Upon Removing the Tefillin?" in this article https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/removing-tefillin "Removing the Tefillin" by Rabbi David Brofsky

@DoubleAA , the MB and Be'er Heitiv address that...
